# npm proxy settings not getting removed

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

using ubuntu 12.04 and npm 1.4.28 When I do:

```
npm config get proxy
```

I get:

```
http://10.7.192.1:8080/
```

to remove that I did the following:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

I also removed the .npmrc file and doing the **get** command again it returns:

```
http://10.7.192.1:8080/
```

It's driving me crazy, is there any way to remove this?

**EDIT:** I also tried [THIS](http://luxiyalu.com/how-to-remove-all-npm-proxy-settings/) but still the same result.

**EDIT2:** This is the output of npm config list:

```
; default values
always-auth = false
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
cache = "/home/arash/.npm"
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cafile = undefined
cert = null
color = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
editor = "vi"
email = ""
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
global = false
globalconfig = "/usr/local/etc/npmrc"
globalignorefile = "/usr/local/etc/npmignore"
group = 1000
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = "https://10.7.192.1:8080/"<<<<<-----------------
ignore-scripts = false
init-module = "/home/arash/.npm-init.js"
init.author.email = ""
init.author.name = ""
init.author.url = ""
init.license = "ISC"
json = false
key = null
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "warn"
; long = false (overridden)
message = "%s"
node-version = "0.10.33"
npat = false
onload-script = null
optional = true
parseable = false
prefix = "/usr/local"
production = false
proprietary-attribs = true
proxy = "http://10.7.192.1:8080/" <<<<<-----------------
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = false
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-exact = false
save-optional = false
save-prefix = "^"
searchexclude = null
searchopts = ""
searchsort = "name"
shell = "/bin/bash"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-tag = false
spin = true
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tmp = "/tmp"
umask = 2
unicode = true
unsafe-perm = true
usage = false
user = 0
; user-agent = "npm/{npm-version} node/{node-version} {platform} {arch}" (overridden)
userconfig = "/home/arash/.npmrc"
username = ""
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "man"
```

as you can see the proxy and https-proxy is still set to "http://10.7.192.1:8080/" and it's not getting removed.

Comment: Did you try this in a new terminal after all the cleanup.

Comment: yes, and the result is still the same

Comment: `npm config rm proxy` works for me

Comment: how did you set it? using: `npm config set proxy "value"` And what version of nom (I use v2.14.3)

Comment: `npm --version`? Have you tried running `npm config list` to see where the setting is coming from (either your global `.npmrc` or a local, project-specific one)? Have you tried using the `-g` or `--global` flag to tell `npm` to edit your global configuration?

Comment: @nash_ag npm config rm proxy didn't work for me, I also tried setting the proxy to google and then removing it and it was replaced again

Comment: @Kenan I've udpated my question, please to refer to EDIT2 for that

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling npm/node?

Comment: @NooBskie Ain't that what windows users usually do? I'll try to see what's causing this and then if nothing works then I'll consider using that as a last resort.

Comment: Well all the conventional methods that should work aren't working so something has to be botched somewhere else. npm doesnt take long at all to reinstall and you can still save all your packages just seems like a faster route for me

Comment: @NooBskie I've deleted npm, node and everything... using the command in npm website and removing everything from it. Installed node again and npm proxy is still set to that proxy !!!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple installations of npm or node somewhere?